# Есть ли ограничения у полей mysql?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдает такую ошибку при создания таблицы, если ставлю дефолтные значения или аннотацию поменьше @Column(length = 500), то все создается. В этой таблице 13 колонок.

Создавая с 3 колонками таблицу и с @Column(length = 5000), все работает.

Какие тут ограничения?)

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table post (id bigint not null, avto varchar(255), city varchar(255), dolz varchar(255), educ varchar(1000), educ1 varchar(1000), educ2 varchar(1000), educ3 varchar(1000), educ4 varchar(1000), family varchar(255), fio varchar(255), komand varchar(255), language varchar(255), obyaz varchar(1000), obyaz1 varchar(1000), obyaz2 varchar(1000), obyaz3 varchar(1000), obyaz4 varchar(1000), obyaz5 varchar(1000), obyaz6 varchar(1000), obyaz7 varchar(1000), obyaz8 varchar(1000), obyaz9 varchar(1000), oseve varchar(1000), pereezd varchar(255), period varchar(1000), period1 varchar(1000), period2 varchar(1000), period3 varchar(1000), period4 varchar(1000), period5 varchar(1000), period6 varchar(1000), period7 varchar(1000), period8 varchar(1000), period9 varchar(1000), profnav varchar(1000), razdel varchar(255), rec varchar(255), stazh varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at search_for_applicant.site.SiteApplication.main(SiteApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:762) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:646) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Spring. phpMyAdmin.Hibernate

Comment: @Kromster даже если все колонки просуммировать  до 65535 не доходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил. Изменил тип поля на longtext

для hibernate @Column(length = 5000)
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")

Comment: @Kromster  мне помогает, что я не один пытаюсь найти решение (успокаивает)

Answer (score 2):

varchar полей в таблице объявлено на

```
255x3+1000x5+255x4+1000x11+255+1000x11+255x3 = 29 805
```

символов. Внимание, это важно.

В байтах это всё счастье будет занимать от одного до 4 байт на символ, в зависимости от используемой кодировки. В расчёт здесь учитывается именно максимальная длина поля - от 29805 байт до 119220 байт сырых данных. У вас скорее всего настроено использование utf8 (алиас для `utf8mb3`, 3 байта на символ) или даже `utf8mb4` (4 байта на строку).

В mysql существует [ограничение](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html) в 64 килобайта на строку данных. Вот и всё, у вас таблица может потребовать больше места для одной строки, потому mysql говорит, что вам нужно пересмотреть структуру. Поля blob и text хранятся немного отдельно и не участвуют в полном объёме в подсчёте размера строки (9-12 байт на поле).

---

По типам данных и общей структуре таблицы есть вопросы о том, насколько вы проработали схему данных.

Comment: вы имеете в виду, что для числовых полей нужно брать числовые типы данных, для длинных полей длинные типы данных и т.д. ?

Comment: имею в виду поля с повторяющимися именами - не нужно ли в нормальную форму привести? Длины varchar на вид так же выбраны с потолка.